# Bluetooth on Acer Aspire E1-572G under Ubuntu 14.04: no device found

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, acer

I am quite new to Ubuntu so I was surfing on this forum but didn't find a real answer to my question, which is:

When Bluetooth is on and I try to pair any device, the search doesn't list any result and even if my laptop should be visible, I can't see it on other devices like smartphones.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I fixed it by upgrading the ubuntu linux kernel to version 3.16.1-031601-generic. You can download the kernel from [ubuntu kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline)
There are three files which you can install after download one by one with the software center:

linux-image-3.16.1-031601-generic_3.16.1-031601.201408140014_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.16.1-031601-generic_3.16.1-031601.201408140014_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.16.1-031601_3.16.1-031601.201408140014_all.deb

(notice to use correct arch amd64/i386 but acer e1-572 is a 64bit machine)